# How can a user upload audio for use in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, web-audio-api

I'm building a single page web app with node and express. I would like the user to be able to upload their own audio file so it can be played back in the browser.

I have tried using the `<form>` and `<input>` tags with `type="file"` but how can I get the audio file from that and use it in the browser for use with the web audio API?

Any help would be much appreciated thank you.

Comment: use phonegap or audioisland

Comment: Do you need to get the audio file back to your server, or can this all be done client-side?

Comment: I'd like to do it all client side - it doesn't need to go to the server at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the initDragDropOfAudioFiles() method in main.js in my Vocoder demo (webaudiovocoder.appspot.com, on github at http://github.com/cwilso/Vocoder).  It sets up an element as a drag/drop receiver of audio files for use by Web Audio.  It'll need a bit of generalizing to work for you, but it should be straightforward.